# s3 serverside encryption using oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, encryption, amazon-s3, oozie, distcp

I have a sqoop job which will write the data into s3 bucket. If I run this job from command line it is encrypting the s3 files. But if I use the same jar file to run sqoop job using oozie workflow then it is pushing the data to s3 but encryption is not happened.

Below is the my oozie workflow.

```
    <java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <main-class>com.aa.datalake.ingest.util.SqoopIngestUtil</main-class>
        <arg>root</arg>
        <arg>root</arg>
        <arg>test</arg>
    <arg>avro</arg>
    <arg>sqoop-demo</arg>   
    </java>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="email-action" />
</action>
```

Inside jar we are copying the data from hdfs to s3 using distcp command.

So how I can do the server side encryption for s3 files using oozie workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the above issue by enabling the s3 encryption in EMR cluster before launching the cluster.